# array push with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

a need to know how add a value to this array. I don't know how to push with a "value description".

```
  $scope.friends = [
{name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
{name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
{name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'}  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$scope.friends = [
{name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
{name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
{name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'}  ];

/* push new record */
$scope.friends.push({
    name: 'example',
    age: 54,
    gender: 'girl'
});
```